# Queue size and blocking for intermittent connections

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

This question is about how Python queues (from the queue module) work when they have reached their maximum size but additional items continue to appear at their input.

I am working on a Python program that reads data from multiple serial ports, partitions the data into multiple queues, and provides a TCP socket server that accepts connections on multiple ports, each port serving one queue.  The program works like this:

- Each of four serial port threads continuously dumps data for two channels into a common input queue (a total of eight 25-30 character records/second).
- Another thread get()s the input queue and splits the data into nine output queues (one for each channel, plus one that contains all channels).
- Then each of nine socket threads, when a connection is made, get()s the data from its queue and sends it to the client.

Amazingly, my code seems to work, but I want to ensure that it is robust.  A concern is that the serial ports are continuously outputting data, but the client connections to pull that data from the queues are intermittent.

In that case, what does the output look like when a client connects?  The contents of the queue will be sent immediately, but what happens once the old data is gone?  e.g., if the queue size is 10 but the producer thread has pumped 1000 items into it with no get() calls, once the ten items are consumed what comes out next -- item 11, or item 1001?  In other words, are the items that have arrived since the queue blocked thrown out, with the next insertion being the first data that arrives once there is room, or are they inserted in order?

I've tried a few tests and all I've been able to determine is that if the queue sizes are set too small, I get initial output and then finally (after the timeout period) the program terminates with a "Queue Empty" message.  If the queue size is set to 1000 or so, the program seems to run continuously, but it's hard to tell if I'm losing data.

It's OK if I lose the oldest samples, but I can't have gaps -- item 10 must be followed by item 11, not item 1001.  Does the queue mechanism work that way, or is there something I need to do to ensure this behavior?  (I suppose the queue size could be infinite, but I suspect that might cause other problems after the program has been running for a while.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself...

Summary: when a queue is full you either have to (a) block, stalling everything upstream, or (b) throw new inputs on the floor until there's room.

First, my program stopped after some (variable) time.  This happened when one of the output queues that was not being read filled up.  That's fixed by testing before putting an item in the queue:

```
if not q.full():
    q.put(item)
```

If the queue is full, drop new items on the floor.  When you start pulling data from the queue, you get the queue contents up until it was filled, then the new data once there is room.  That is a problem because I need an uninterrupted sequence of items in my output.

To fix this, I empty the queue before reading out the data:

```
while not q.empty():
    line = q.get()    # toss this
while True:
    line = q.get()
    conn.send(line)
    q.task_done()
```

I lose the old queued data (but that's OK in my application) and now I get sequential output without gaps.